# count total number of selected radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm setting up a WordPress site using ACF to get some extra user info on registration, and I got a radio button field which I need to count how many of each choice there has been selected and display it on the frontend for all users

Do you have any idea on how I can do this?

The radio button is added to the user registration and is saved to the wp_usermeta, as far as I can see.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem you've provided enough information for anybody to be able to help you effectively. I'd recommend browsing the [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation and editing this or re-asking your question with the code snippets you've tried, and your desired output. Keep in mind we need a [Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to really help you. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: all sorts of ways, but not sure i've attached it the right way, so i'm more looking for a direction than a fixed answer